# How to run an ActiveRecord query with not numeric offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

For instance:

```
Entry.order(:id).offset('RANDOM() * 10000').limit(5)
```

Currently it converts string offset into integer 0.

Comment: What's wrong with generating the random offset in ruby? `Entry.order(:id).offset(rand(10000)).limit(5)`

Comment: What's happening is that rails is calling "to_i" on the value passed to the `.offset` method: most of the time this is the best thing to do, as you're likely to pass through either an integer or an integer in string from, eg from a parameter.  In this case it's letting you down.  I would do as @GergoErdosi suggests and get your random number in rails first.